# Upper Triangular matrix

Tags: cuda

i want to create upper triangular matrix with cuda

In the upper triangular matrix, the elements located
ed below the diagonal are zeros. This function should assign
the given value to the other elements.

but below code assigns all values as 0 why?

```
__global__ void initUpperTrinagleGPU(int *devMatrix, int numR, int numC, int value) {
    int x = blockDim.x*blockIdx.x + threadIdx.x;
    int y = blockDim.y*blockIdx.y + threadIdx.y;

    int offset = y * numC + x;

    if(numC <= numR) {
        devMatrix[offset] = 0;
    }
    else
        devMatrix[offset] = value;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This condition is wrong `if(numC <= numR)`, it is true if there are less or equal cols than rows.

This might work, but it's just out of my head, not tested:

```
if(x >= y) {
    devMatrix[offset] = 0;
}
else {
    devMatrix[offset] = value;
}
```

note, that you should wrap this into another condition like:

```
if(y < numR && x < numC) { ...
```